# CSS - Print large lists with correct page breaking?

Tags: css, jstree

I try to prepare jsTree content to printing, and I have some troubles with page 'margins'. The problem is a last line on page is cutting by his height. Please, look at this - [image: screenshot]

Is it possible to fix it?

p.s. I prepared zipped example, with only jsTree files - [download](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13145912/jstree-print.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `page-break-inside` and use it within a `@media` query for your CSS.

```
@media print {
  ul, ul li {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

This will tell the browser when in print mode, avoid breaking of the lines or text.

Current Browser support:

- Chrome - 1.0+
- Firefox (Gecko) - 19.0+
- Internet Explorer - 8.0+
- Opera - 7.0+
- Safari - 1.3+ (312)

Comment: I try this, but with no result

Comment: No I can't because I use framework and many separated files. But I create other clear example with only jsTree files, and this problem not reproduces on it. I don't understand what is wrong with my files...

Comment: I prepared zipped example, with only jsTree files. Looks like troubles with the jsTree styles - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13145912/jstree-print.zip

Answer (score 0):

Set `page-break-inside: avoid;` on the `<li>` elements.